# SSRS operations across lines of the same dataset - Subsetting - Lookup

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I've got the following dataset:

[image]

I need to show in SSRS two lines: One corresponding to Sales for IsControl = 0 and the other one corresponding to IsControl = 1. 
However, for the line that has a control = 1 Sales will have to be divided for the its Num_Of_Customers and multiplied for the Num_of_Customers of the same week_of_day where IsControl = 0.

In other words I'm scaling sales for IsControl = 1 to IsControl = 0. In a way that I can show the two lines on a line plot.

What is the SSRS expression to do that?

Sales and Num_Of_Customers in this case are equivalent for IsControl = 0 and IsControl = 1 but they are normally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the expression below should do what you need.

```
=IIf(Fields!IsControl.Value = 1,
    Fields!Sales.Value/Lookup(Fields!week_of_day.Value.ToString() & "0", 
        Fields!week_of_day.Value.ToString() & Fields!IsControl.Value.ToString(), 
        Fields!Num_Of_Customers.Value, 
        "DataSet1"),
    Fields!Sales.Value*Fields!Num_Of_Customers.Value)
```

If `IsControl` is 1, lookup the number of customers where `IsControl` is 0 for the same date, and divide `Sales` by that number. Otherwise, multiply `Sales` by the number of customers in the same row.

If you just need Sales for the rows where `IsControl` is 0, use this:

```
=IIf(Fields!IsControl.Value = 1,
    Fields!Sales.Value/Lookup(Fields!week_of_day.Value.ToString() & "0", 
        Fields!week_of_day.Value.ToString() & Fields!IsControl.Value.ToString(), 
        Fields!Num_Of_Customers.Value, 
        "DataSet1"),
    Fields!Sales.Value)
```

Whatever you need, the `Lookup` will get you to the row where `IsControl` is 0. Pull the value you need and do what ever math is necessary.

Good luck!